# Map Alt-Left to word-forward in SecureCRT Linux terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, putty, securecrt

I use Putty and SecureCRT to connect to a Linux server.

The following keyboard commands work out of the box with Putty:

- `Alt-b` or `Alt-←` : move backward one word
- `Alt-f` or `Alt-→` : move forward one word

However, with SecureCRT, `Alt-←` and `Alt-→` have no effect.

It seems like I have two options to make this work with SecureCRT:

- Map `Alt-←` to `Alt-b` in SecureCRT settings
- Do the same kind of mapping in my `~/.inputrc`

Either way, I am completely lost, because I don't know the *string* or *escape sequence* correponding to `Alt-b`

**How should I proceed ?**

Answer (score 2):

Check the "Use Alt as meta key" checkbox for the session, found in Options  -> Session Options -> Terminal -> Emulation -> Emacs.